# I Installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a dell Inspiron 1501 along side windows vista using the windows installer but it wont boot into Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, boot-failure

I Installed Ubuntu  12.04 on a dell Inspiron 1501 with an AMD 64 along side windows vista using the windows installer but it wont boot into Ubuntu. It shows that Ubuntu is on the system when my computer boots up but when I select it to load it goes into a black screen and displays some error messages and tells me that the is no operating system installed. 
this is the error that i get:

```
Try (hdo, 0):FAT16:no WUBILDR
try (hdo, 1)NTFS: error: "Prefix" is not set.
symbol not found:'grub_file_get_device_name'
Aborted.
Broadcom UNDI PXE-2.1 V2-1.0
copyright (c) 2000-2006 Broadcom corporation
copyright (c) 1997-2000 Intel corporation
All rights reserved

PXE-EC8:PXE structure was not found in UNDI driver code segment.
PXE-M0F Broadcom PXE Rom
Operating system not found
```

How can I fix this?  I have tryed re-installing it but i get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

A file installation after the installation of main setup will occur online(be sure about that your system must be connected to internet). After the installation please reboot your system and you will be able to run your Ubuntu 12.04 easily.

Comment: during the installation? I was connected at this time

Comment: yes...when the setup installation will be completed after then the update file will run...it will complete the setup files to boot proper in your system.

Comment: befor or after it asks me to reboot

Comment: after the installation...and if it is your first of Ubuntu then you have to careful.

Comment: so after the installation i need to keep the internet on.  But i have to reboot the computer.

Comment: so i need to wait before i reboot the computer?

Comment: is it possible to run the update file manually?

Comment: actually i got same problem when i installed the Ubuntu on my system..so i am suggesting you you should try this one...

Answer (score 0):

How is your part of hard disk where you installed Ubuntu shown in Windows Vista by the 'Disk Manager'? You can open 'Disk Manager' using diskmgmt.msc command in "Windows --> Run". Is it shown as Healthy/Unknown partition. If not, the partition is getting corrupted during the installation process somewhere.

Better try for installing Ubuntu after Windows Vista is installed. This will keep you away from lots of troubles.

**UPDATE**

Since the hard disk partition is shown healthy, then it is not a partition corruption issue. If you don't have any problem reinstalling your computer again, then I would suggest you do that. When you do, install Windows Vista first and then install Ubuntu.

Comment: it says that it is healthy

Comment: I just updated the answer after your comment

Comment: windows vista is already installed on my computer.  I'm just trying to install Ubuntu as a secondary operating system.

Comment: i've tried re-installing it about 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

So you are installing Ubuntu with the Wubi program from within MS Windows 7?

Have you checked that your copy of the Ubuntu installer has the right checksum? Your downloaded copy might have been corrupted in some way.

Are you installing the 32 bit or 64 bit version of Ubuntu? I would ask you to try the 64 bit, as there are a problem with the 32 bit installer. The problem with the 32 bit version can still be solved by uninstall one package from the installer image, but it is easier to use the 64 bit.

Comment: i am trying the 32bit right now i will go a head and get the 64bit and give it a try.

Comment: can i get it as a 64 bit using the windows installer